# Spring RESTful app Java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, jsp, spring-mvc

I work with Spring RESTful app and it's working fine. The Rest `URL` provides JSON based data and is mapped with `RequestMapping` annotation. In the landing URL `[localhost:8080]`, I would like to have a JSP page `index.jsp` with some infos. I would like to do it with Java based annotation and it's not working. I mean now I even dont get the JSON based data as well unless commmented out the `WebServletConfiguration` file. The project structure is provided below,

[image]

I provided the files in the `configuration` folder,

**HelloWorldInitializer.java**

```
public class HelloWorldInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websystique.springmvc")
public class HelloWorldConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "Views")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsps/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**WebServletConfiguration.java**

```
public class WebServletConfiguration implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webCtx.register(HelloWorldConfiguration.class);
        webCtx.setServletContext(ctx);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = ctx.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webCtx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

I get this msg in the console,

```
[2017-07-31 03:45:37,499] Artifact Spring4MVCCRUDRestService:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
31-Jul-2017 15:45:37.882 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2017-07-31 03:45:37,938] Artifact Spring4MVCCRUDRestService:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-07-31 03:45:37,938] Artifact Spring4MVCCRUDRestService:war exploded: Deploy took 439 milliseconds
31-Jul-2017 15:45:46.973 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.16/webapps/manager]
31-Jul-2017 15:45:47.019 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.16/webapps/manager] has finished in [45] ms
```

The relevent controller calling is here,

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHome() {
        return "index";
    }

// some code 
// ..........
// ..........
 }
```

Here is the `pom.xml` file,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.form.handler</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>SpringFormHandler</artifactId>
    <name>Form Handler</name>


    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>5.0.1.Final</version>-->
        <!--<type>pom</type>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now, all in the landing page and all other URL, I get the `Http 404 Error`.

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: The API docs of [`ServletContext.addServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet-java.lang.String-javax.servlet.Servlet-) say that it may return `null` if there is already a servlet registered with the specified name. So it looks like a servlet under the name `dispatcher` is already registered somewhere else.

Comment: I updated the `pom.xml` file and don't have that error message now. I have no error message now. PLease, read the updated question.

Comment: Then what is the problem now? The message that you get in the console only says that the webapp has been deployed successfully.

Comment: I updated the question. I get `404` everywhere now

Comment: At least, answer me of one question: Can I have `JSP` and `JSON` in the same webapp serving data provided all the config is correct?

Comment: Put this line `ctx.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(webCtx));` after registering your config class, and let me know the status [e.g: after this line `webCtx.register(HelloWorldConfiguration.class);`]

Comment: Indeed, nothing changed

Comment: Which url you entered in the browser?

Comment: @Jesper When I changed the servlet name, it dont show any error. Still I dont get the JSP page though. It returns `index` as the String in the main page, not the JSP page.

Comment: @RestController not render index.jsp. To render jsp etc. page , create normal controller. and to provide json objects, use restcontroller.

Comment: Okay, this is one of the issues that I was suspicious about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a @Controller class which returns a view, in this case `index.jsp`, using Spring Viewresolver.

`@RestContoller`, that implicitly `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`, constitute the body of the HTTP response as typically JSON or XML. That is why you see index as the string.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't "HelloWorldConfiguration.class" be passed to getServletConfigClasses ?

```
public class HelloWorldInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what have done there. Do you mean the `WebServletConfiguration` class?

Comment: Looks like you passed "HelloWorldConfiguration.class" to the getRootConfigClasses() not **getServletConfigClasses()**

Comment: Thanks, will get back to you soon. Seems like a good asnwer to me.

Comment: it doesnt help either. I just too tired after the whole day this simple crap. tell me one thing: can I have other JSP and the JSON in the same app from the controller?